# Include module path phpunit

Tags: php, phpunit

I have a problem including my module for my unit test, I have tried some things but nothings works 
I have a directory src with my module and a directory test with bootstrap.php,phpunit.xml and my tests

Using set_include_path:

```
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    '.',
    __DIR__ . '/path/to/mymodule',
    get_include_path()
)));
```

adding with loader:

```
$loader->add('mymodule', '/path/to/mymodule');
```

And when I use `get_include_path()` I can see the path to my module but in my test he can't find classes from my module

Comment: What kind of loader? Composer? ? PSR-0 or PSR-4 ? Classmaps or dynamic? Try phpunit with PSR-0.

Comment: composer but my module is in a directory above

Comment: PSR-0 ? PSR-4 ? Classmaps ? Read here how to use composer autoloading: https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading